# How to get Power Spectral Density of file using this research paper method?

Tags: python, power-spectral-density, spectrogram

I came across this research paper. In this they have mentioned power spectral density calculation of various file. I have read the paper and try to calculate and plot the graph, don't know it correct or not? Don't know how to compute frequency marginal, plot and next step?

[A Signal Processing Approach for Cyber Data Classification with Deep Neural Networks](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915029865)

> we consider is to treat the byte sequence as a signal (with amplitude ranging from 0 to 255), and transform it into frequency space. A similar technique has shown success characterizing sections of DNA in bioinformatics9 . While the Fourier transform of the entropy has been considered for identifying malware5 , entropy alone is too low dimensional a representation to capture the full complexity of data, since it cannot be uniquely transformed to the original sequence. On the other hand, the complex Fourier transform is invertible and exactly captures the data sequence. Nevertheless, for simplicity and speed, we compute the power spectral density from a spectrogram with 256 positive frequency bins. The entire spectrogram is then summed over the time axis to compute the frequency marginal, as given by (2). Here, x is the sequence of byte values (0 to 255) in the data, and w is a rectangular window function. The summation over time collapses it into a single spectrum with a fixed number of frequency bins. Finally, the area of the spectrum is normalized to unit value, since the total power would otherwise be determined by the file length. If this normalization is not performed, the classifier can learn to discriminate based partially upon file length.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import spectrogram, get_window

def get_byte_sequence(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            byte_sequence = file.read()
            return byte_sequence
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File '{file_path}' not found.")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return None

def compute_frequency_marginal(byte_sequence, window_size, sampling_rate, num_frequency_bins):
    # Convert the byte values to integers
    integer_sequence = np.frombuffer(byte_sequence, dtype=np.uint8)

    window = get_window('rect', window_size)
    
    # Compute the spectrogram with the specified window function
    _, frequencies, Sxx = spectrogram(integer_sequence, fs=sampling_rate, window=window, nperseg=window_size)

    # Select only the positive frequencies
    
    # Sum the squared magnitudes along the positive frequency bins

    return positive_frequencies, frequency_marginal

def plot_frequency_marginal(frequencies, frequency_marginal):
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(frequencies, 10 * np.log10(frequency_marginal + 1e-10))
    plt.title('Frequency Marginal (Positive 256 Frequency Bins)')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    plt.ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

file_path = 'data/pdf/001.pdf'
byte_sequence = get_byte_sequence(file_path)

if byte_sequence is not None:
    window_size = 256
    sampling_rate = 1.0  # For simplicity, assuming one sample per byte
    num_frequency_bins = 256
    
    frequencies, frequency_marginal = compute_frequency_marginal(byte_sequence, window_size, sampling_rate, num_frequency_bins)
    plot_frequency_marginal(frequencies, frequency_marginal)
```